# why are fonts larger when .html page is put on the server?

Tags: fonts, font-size

I wrote a simple page with a header and a lot of text for the body. While I was writing, I tested the page locally on chrome and firefox and the font size seemed to follow what I specified in the css file. However, after I uploaded the html page to the server and looked at it on the specified web address, all the fonts in the body looks 20% larger than what I specified in the css doc.

I am looking for any tips anyone can provide to help me fix this weird bug.

Thanks!

Comment: it's like that on all browsers?

Comment: It might be worth checking a couple of things: make sure the page has the correct path to the css file and make sure the css file that it is referring to is the one/version you are expecting it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I once encountered this too. I had a local version of my homepage and the uploaded version appeared larger. When I looked into it I found out that it was just the browsers zoom-level that was set differently. I don't exactly know why but I could easily change it.